VS Code view js console output when browser dev tools is disabled?
Background: I teach basic web development in a high school. Our technology department has disabled developer tools on all web browsers for student accounts after a recent cyber attack. I need a workaround to allow students to see console output that can be implemented without installing any additional software for two basic scenarios.
Scenario #1: Using VS Code web through a Github codespace. I could swear that I found an extension at one point that would show console output, but I haven't been able to locate it again. All the ones I have tried are dependent on browser dev tools being available.
Scenario #2: Using an online platform such as CodeHS, code.org, etc. Maybe there's a website out there that simulates developer tools? I haven't been able to find anything that will work.
Any advice on how to get students access to something like dev tools without dev tools would be greatly appreciated.

I dont know how performant the computers are at your school, but an option could be to use software like VirtualBox to run everything in a virtual machine, this would safeguard most security risks as far as I know and within this virtual machine everything could be accessed. It could also be a good introduction into Ubuntu for the students :-P

An easier fix could be to teach your students the alert function to display values on the screen and make them see what values exist.

@LarsVonk alert is a horrible debugging tool as it stops the code and requires dismissing a modal. console.log should always be preferred, and taught to students the sooner the better.

"Our technology department has disabled developer tools" - how did they do that? Does chrome://inspect still work? "Maybe there's a website out there that simulates developer tools?" - certainly, since devtools are a website (running in a privileged frame, but still). I wouldn't be surprised if something like https://stackblitz.com could run a full browser in their web containers…

@LarsVonk alert is what we have been using since we don't have console access. Beyond requiring dismissal, it doesn't catch exceptions or do much to help students who are struggling to learn syntax.

@Bergi I'm not sure how they have disabled developer tools. chrome://inspect will still open the tab, but will not allow the developer window to open or to inspect anything. The inspect option in any menu is disabled (greyed out) and ctrl+shift+i does nothing. Stackblitz.com is new to me, so I'll have to look into it further. I previously used repl.it which has an integrated console and basic inspection tool, but repl.it abandoned their "teams for education" so I've switch over to github classroom which uses vs code web.

@LarsVonk the technology dept has looked into using virtual machines but it has been cost prohibitive. I appreciate the suggestions

@Bergi it concerns a course for high school level web development though, I think learning the concept of how variables work is enough, but I digress. I think the suggestion to use something like stackblitz or codepen is great and a much better solution than using the alert. I think it would be good to look into these. (See answer)

There are tools available for demoing code in the browser such as Stackblitz or codepen that could serve this purpose. You can create basic websites and preview them, there is also the option of opening the console.
I personally prefer codepen as it does not require someone to register and you can access the console (bottom left button) and see it's contents. To open codepen without registering go to the link
codepen.io/pen
This suggestion was done in the comments by @Bergi so credits to him.

Stackblitz almost works except that it requires paid premium accounts to access repos from github organizations which is what github classroom uses and what I've been using with my classes. However, if we're still in this situation in the future, I might be able to rework my setup to use Stackblitz. None of these suggestions will help when students are working on the instructional websites anyway. The real solution is for the district to get its act together and setup our labs with the appropriate tools. Leaving the question unanswered for now. Thanks for the help!!

I think codepen is free
